# UITableViewCell Detail Text Label Text Color

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uilabel

I have noticed that if I instantiate UITableViewCell instances programmatically, specifying the style `.value1` (UITableViewCellStyleValue1), the main text label text color is black, but the detail text label text color is a light shade of gray (not quite exactly `UIColor.gray` or `UIColor.lightGray`, though).

**However,** if I use a storyboard with prototype, static cells and set their Style attribute to "Right Detail" (which appears to be the Interface Builder equivalent of `.value1`), both labels are black.

I can navigate the cell's subviews all the way to the label and change the text color in the attribute inspector, but I'm not sure the color preset is there.

**Is there a right way to unify the appearances** of cells in both scenarios, while keeping the traditional gray color in the detail text label?

*(I **would** use dynamic cells and instantiate them programmatically, but this one view controller just happens to have these off-the-shelf cells side-by-side with more complex, custom cells.)*

Comment: just check if you are not confusing it with .subtitle

Comment: Subtitle is displayed below the main label, also to the left. In both cases I have the `detailTextLabel` on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and logged a bug report in the Apple Bug Reporter. My bug report was closed with the comments "Duplicate of 28317724 (Open)". I am not sure if bug reports other than your own are visible, the system does not appear to be very transparent.

Answer (score 4):

I was also annoyed by the same problem.

Finally I found that Xcode 7.3.1 generated a detail text label with text color R:142, G:142, B:147 (#8E8E93).
Xcode 8.2 generates it with black text color. ('Default', to be exact)

Anyway, changing the label's color to R:142, G:142, B:147 (#8E8E93) is an appropriate one, I think so.